# In Laravel 4.2 I cannot style a dropdown with boostrap - get default style intead

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to make my dropdowns in Laravel look like the rest of the form fields, which are using form-control styles from bootstrap.
Here is what I tried. I also tried wrapping the form in a div with the form control class but no luck.

`{{ Form::select('company_id', $company_lists, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}`

form-control works fine on selects, but not when using the lists as above (ie populating from the database). Any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your array containing the class is being passed as the default value for the select. (http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html#method_select)

Try changing it to:

`{{ Form::select('company_id', $company_lists, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}`